# Creating alpha channel opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a program in c++ and opencv2 that loads an mp4 file and gives me frame pixels. I have a problem opencv outputs 24 bits per pixel, and I need 32 to display in a window on winapi. Is it possible to create an empty alpha channel using standard opencv tools?

Comment: cv::cvtColor with BGR2BGRA parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`cv::cvtColor`**](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) to convert a 3 channel RGB/BGR image to a 4 channel image with an additional alpha channel.
As you can see in the documentation link above, the **3rd parameter** specifies the **required conversion**.

```
cv::Mat img24;  // initialized somehow
// ...
cv::Mat img32;
cv::cvtColor(img24, img32, CV_BGR2BGRA);
```